# select value from multiple columns mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database

On my site a user enters an account number and I have a script to show the business name belonging to that account number, however the account number could be in 2 columns.

I have the below code to search 1 of the columns (personID);

```
sql="SELECT * FROM member WHERE personID = '".$q."'";
```

How do I edit this code to search 2 columns (personID & another column) for the account number?

Comment: `WHERE personId = 'something' OR other_column = 'something'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the SQL OR is what you're looking for. Might be worth taking a look here http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_and_or.asp

```
sql="SELECT * FROM member WHERE personID = '".$q."' OR othercolumn = '".$q."'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use OR:

```
sql="SELECT * FROM member WHERE personID = '".$q."' OR anotherColumn = '".$q."'";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `in`:

```
sql="SELECT * FROM member WHERE '".$q."' IN (personID, othercol)"
```

The advantage of `in` is that the parameter is only mentioned once.  This makes it easier to use proper parameters rather than string substitution -- a much better approach to generating SQL.